# Tkinter Event Handler Unable to See Global Variables

Tags: python, tkinter

Whenever the `on_click` event handler is invoked for my button its method doesn't acknowledge the existence of my global variable.

What is occurring to cause this, and how do/can I access my global variables inside the event handler?

I've already tried passing the value of the global variable into the method,

```py
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput import mouse

import tkinter as tk
import sys

controller = Controller()
recordings = []
is_recording = False
listener = None
top = tk.Tk()


class Recording:
    def __init__(self):
        self.actions = []
        self.key_bind_code = -1

    def add_action(self):
        self.actions.append(controller.position)

    def play(self):
        for action in actions:
            do_action(action)


def on_click(recording):
    recording.add_action()

def start_recording():
    r = Recording()
    recordings.append(r)
    listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click(r))
    listener.start()

def stop_recording():
    listener.stop()

def handle_recording():
    print("Recording: " + str(is_recording))
    if is_recording:
        stop_recording()
        is_recording = False
    else:
        start_recording()
        is_recording = True


button = tk.Button(top, text="Record", command=handle_recording)
button.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

When the handler is invoked, this is the message I receive.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pdiddy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "repeat.py", line 60, in handle_recording
    print("Recording: " + str(is_recording))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'is_recording' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Within `handle_recording()`, `is_recording` is a local variable by default (since the function contains an assignment to it).  You'd need a `global` statement in that function to access the global variable of the same name.

Comment: The `mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click(r))` calls `on_click(r)` and passes its return value as the value  of the `on_click` keyword argument to `mouse.Listener()` — is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! The use of global was what I was looking for.

Comment: I know it's not what you asked about, but it's still wrong — which is why I mentioned it down here in a comment instead of posting like it was an answer.

Comment: @martineau, it was not what I was intending for. I just wanted to bind an event to a mouse-click action. If you have time, could you please tell me what is wrong with the way I'm doing it?

Comment: John: Sorry I can't really help you further because it's unclear to me what you're actually trying to accomplish (plus I don't even have `pynput` installed). Regardless, let me say I think it's very unlikely that it can be used with `tkinter` which does its own handling of mouse and keyboard events in its `mainloop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `is_recording` not be considered a local variable in the `handle_recording()` function, you must declare that it isn't one by adding a `global is_recording` statement to the beginning of the function. Like this:

```
def handle_recording():
    global is_recording  # ADD THIS LINE.
    print("Recording: " + str(is_recording))
    if is_recording:
        stop_recording()
        is_recording = False
    else:
        start_recording()
        is_recording = True
```

While one can **read** the value of an existing global variable that hasn't been declared `global` — because of the way Python looks up values — to **change** the value of one however, you *must* explicitly declare it as a `global`. By convention the recommended place to do that is at the very beginning of the block of code within which it's being manipulated (the function here).